# Dynamic Array of ints in j2me

Tags: arrays, java-me

I want to do a simple dynamic array of ints in my j2me application,

The only dynamic array I see is "java.util.Vector" and this one doesn't seem to accept an int as a new element (only wants Objects).

So how do I go around fixing that problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public class DynamicIntArray
{
    private static final int CAPACITY_INCREMENT = 10;
    private static final int INITIAL_CAPACITY   = 10;

    private final int capacityIncrement;

    public int   length = 0;
    public int[] array;

    public DynamicIntArray(int initialCapacity, int capacityIncrement)
    {
        this.capacityIncrement = capacityIncrement;
        this.array = new int[initialCapacity];
    }

    public DynamicIntArray()
    {
        this(CAPACITY_INCREMENT, INITIAL_CAPACITY);
    }

    public int append(int i)
    {
        final int offset = length;
        if (offset == array.length)
        {
            int[] old = array;
            array = new int[offset + capacityIncrement];
            System.arraycopy(old, 0, array, 0, offset);
        }
        array[length++] = i;
        return offset;
    }


    public void removeElementAt(int offset)
    {
        if (offset >= length)
        {
            throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException("offset too big");
        }

        if (offset < length)
        {
            System.arraycopy(array, offset+1, array, offset, length-offset-1);
            length--;
        }
    }
}
```

Doesn't have a setAt() method, but I'm sure you get the idea.

Comment: I guess DEFAULT_CAPACITY_INCREMENT, DEFAULT_INITIAL_CAPACITY should not have DEFAULT_ prefix?

Answer (score 6):

You need to box the int in an Integer.

```
v.addElement(new Integer(1));
```

Comment: I ended up using that, the problem is, the best way I found to extract the value is "((Integer)(v.elementAt(index))).intValue()". Is it a java thing or what?

Comment: Use Generics. 
Vector<Integer> v = Vector<Integer>(); 
Integer i = v.elementAt(index);

Comment: You can use generics to type your Vector and then you don't return Objects with elementAt but Inegers instead. Try:

Vector<Integer> v = new Vector<Integer>();
v.elementAt(index)

Autoboxing will convert the Integer to an int for you, no need to use intValue.

Comment: Ain't no generics or autoboxing in J2ME, unfortunately.

Comment: consider changing the answer to this one.