# Java ME String array without size

Tags: java, arrays, java-me, size

I have a simple question ?

```
String[] names  = null ;

names[0] = "Hello"
```

I'm getting an error ..

How could I instantiate array as I don't know the the size limit... help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this?

```
String[] names  = new String[] {  "Hello" };
```

Or you might also use `ArrayList` or `StringCollection`.

**EDIT:**

For J2ME: There was a trick posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1322683/dynamic-array-of-ints-in-j2me%5C) for dynamic array of Ints. I suppose it should possible to convert it for Strings. I have converted that example, however I didn't have J2ME emulator to test it:

```
public class DynamicStringArray {
    private static final int CAPACITY_INCREMENT = 10;
    private static final int INITIAL_CAPACITY = 10;

    private final int capacityIncrement;

    public int length = 0;
    public String[] array;

    public DynamicStringArray(int initialCapacity, int capacityIncrement) {
        this.capacityIncrement = capacityIncrement;
        this.array = new String[initialCapacity];
    }

    public DynamicStringArray() {
        this(CAPACITY_INCREMENT, INITIAL_CAPACITY);
    }

    public int append(String str) {
        final int offset = length;
        if (offset == array.length) {
            String[] old = array;
            array = new String[offset + capacityIncrement];
            System.arraycopy(old, 0, array, 0, offset);
        }
        array[length++] = str;
        return offset;
    }

    public void removeElementAt(int offset) {
        if (offset >= length) {
            throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException("offset too big");
        }

        if (offset < length) {
            System.arraycopy(array, offset + 1, array, offset, length - offset
                    - 1);
            length--;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `ArrayList<String>` when you don't know in advance the array size. What you are doing here is invalid (trying to access a null object).

---

Edit: *as you can't use Vector and ArrayList, you'll have to roll you own implementation of dynamic array. You'll find one almost ready with some explanations on [algolist.net](http://www.algolist.net/Data_structures/Dynamic_array)*. Simply replace the int storage by a String storage.

```
// Warning: not tested!
public class DynamicStringArray {
    private String[] storage;
    private int size;

    public DynamicArray() {
            storage = new String[10];
            size = 0;
    }

    public DynamicArray(int capacity) {
            storage = new String[capacity];
            size = 0;
    }

public void ensureCapacity(int minCapacity) {
    int capacity = storage.length;
    if (minCapacity > capacity) {
        int newCapacity = (capacity * 3) / 2 + 1;
        if (newCapacity < minCapacity)
            newCapacity = minCapacity;
        storage = Arrays.copyOf(storage, newCapacity);
    }
}

private void pack() {
    int capacity = storage.length;
    if (size <= capacity / 2) {
        int newCapacity = (size * 3) / 2 + 1;
        storage = Arrays.copyOf(storage, newCapacity);
    }
}

public void trim() {
    int newCapacity = size;
    storage = Arrays.copyOf(storage, newCapacity);
}

    //...
}
```

Comment: @Muhammad: j2me has Vector, which you can use instead: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3343212/arraylist-in-j2me

Comment: @Thilo: he says in other comment that he can't use Vector for some reason.

Answer (score 3):

try

```
String[] names = new String[1];
names[0] = "Hello";
```

Use an [`ArrayList<String>`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) if you don't know the size beforehand.

```
ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
names.add("hello");
names.add("another string");
...
```

looks like j2me has non-generic [ArrayList](http://download.oracle.com/javame/config/cdc/ref-impl/cdc1.1.2/jsr218/index.html) that you could use like this.

```
ArrayList names = new ArrayList();
names.add("hello");
names.add("another string");
....

String name = (String) names.get(1);
```

Comment: Zero-sized array? You'll get ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException with this snippet :)

Comment: @Muhammad: indeed, that's why others suggested a dynamically-sized data structure.

Answer (score 1):

> How could i instantiate array as I dont know the the size limit

Sorry, that cannot be done. Arrays are of fixed size in Java, and you have to give the size when you create the array.

If you need a flexible buffer, consider using an ArrayList instead. That will grow as needed.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know the size limit (or more generally: almost always) you'll want to use a `List` instead of an array, because it's much more comfortable to handle.

```
List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
names.add("Hello");
```

The reason you're getting an exception (a `NullPointerException`) is that you only defined a variable to reference a `String`-array, but created no `String` array.

You'd have to initialize it like this:

```
String[] names = new String[10];
```

Answer (score 1):

As you are on J2ME and say you can't use arraylist I don't see you having any choice.

You need to choose a reasonable starting size for your array, watch the size, and if you need to add more objects than the size, copy it to a larger array.

With our constraints I cannot think of another way.

Answer (score 1):

As you explained yo want to use it at J2ME there is no ArrayList provided for J2ME however there is an implementation here:

http://kickjava.com/src/j2me/util/ArrayList.java.htm

You can try it.

Also you should consider here too:

http://www1.j2mepolish.org/javadoc/j2me/de/enough/polish/util/ArrayList.html

Comment: dude I had look on that ...du know where its J2ME jar file ..thats javolution.

Comment: An important notice before you implement: http://forum.enough.de/viewtopic.php?t=1308&sid=72721678bd8adb1c189da4f0f48ea00f and the link of jar: http://www.enough.de/products/j2me-polish/download/download/

Comment: Ta Kamaci !! Du know where to get Jar file for the Javolution one ...which supports Arraylist and hashmaps eh ?

Answer (score 1):

you can use with vector

```
Vector strings=new Vector();
strings.addElement("HELLO");
//then convert it to string array
String str[]=new String[strings.size()];
str[0]=(String)strings.get(0);
```

like this..
Hope this helpfull

Comment: i wont ever use this one !! but ta anyway

Comment: Converting collection to array is better done like this: strings.toArray(new String[strings.size()])

Answer (score 1):

```
String str[] = { "ABCde","xyZ","sdsdsdf"} ;

String str[][] = { {"ABC","abc"} ,
                {"pqr","qwerTY"}
              } ;
```